# Measuring the bandwidth used by a GCM app

Tags: android, bandwidth, google-cloud-messaging

I have an Android application that uses Google Cloud Messaging, and I want to measure the amount of bandwidth that the application uses when it receives push notifications. How would I go about approaching this?

Comment: Considering that the maximum payload of a GCM message is 4K, I am not sure that it is worth doing a more formal bandwidth measurement.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But I want to track the overall bandwidth used by push notifications for the application for statistical purposes. Also, I'm not sure if the bandwidth would be a maximum of 4K or if there is an overhead to it